# reading large csv file on python returning nan randomly one of the elements

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am working on machine learning, scanning a large csv file of images paths to associate it to an image to be recognized by the model (40.000 images in my current record). when I created the csv I made sure all the image paths were strings, however when I go to read it with the following code it is randomly saying that some of the image paths are showing up as floats, and then it prints NAN as the value. It seems to be doing it randomly and it is never consistent. Here is my test code to get one that is not a string. Based on this code, since all of them are strings nothing should be printed.

```
for x in df['filepath'].values:
    if type(x) != str:
        print("x", x)
        Index = all_image_paths.index(x)
        print(Index)
```

randomly this is what is printing. And every time it is a different record. In this example it is saying that record index 1884 is NAN.

> x nan 1884

My question is why is this python script randomly misreading the strings?

Comment: I can't really tell you what's happening until I can have some data to test with.

Comment: I'm not sure what all_image_paths is, but if that's the index of the errant line in the CSV, the next step would be to look at that line to see if there is a reason for it to be NaN.

Comment: maybe a line break was inserted by mistake? did you consider dropping missing values before the loop? like `for x in df['filepath'].dropna().values:`?